# Mongo Network Exceptions

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop

I get following network exception, while using Mongo DB:

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: 
                  Interrupted acquiring a permit to retrieve an item from the pool ;
nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoInterruptedException: 
                  Interrupted acquiring a permit to retrieve an item from the pool
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Please edit your question with relevant informations, this isn't a good question at all and it will be flagged to be closed.

Comment: @sureshbojjam did you resolve this error?

Comment: @DecKno    not completely, we increased the connection size in pool.